# Did the update to rb-inotify just break compass on Ruby 1.x?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass

On December 15th [the `rb-inotify` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-inotify) was updated to the version `0.10.0` which now requires `Ruby 2.2` or later. [The `compass` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/) has a runtime dependency of `rb-inotify >= 0.9` which appears to now automatically include version `0.10.0`. Thus on Ruby 1.9.3 when you install `compass`, the installation of `rb-inotify` fails, causing the installation of `compass` to fail.

Have I understood this correctly? Has `rb-inotify` now broken simple commands like `gem install compass` on Ruby 1.x? What is the best way to fix this without updating Ruby?

Comment: Are you using bundler at all? I feel like none of this should break as long as you've installed rb-inotify and specified the version (either in your Gemfile or on your system). Compass is deprecated and hasn't been updated in 4 years and Ruby 1.9.3 was EOL years ago

Comment: Just run `gem install rb-inotify -v 0.9.10` then run `gem install compass`. Works perfectly. It even tells you to do this in the error message when installing compass before rb-inotify is installed: `The last version of rb-inotify (>= 0.9) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 0.9.10. Try installing it with gem install rb-inotify -v 0.9.10 and then running the current command again`

Comment: @anothermh I did try that, but never had any luck, almost as if installing compass tried to reinstall rb-inotify despite me explicitly installing an older version.

Comment: Then do gem uninstall for both and start from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Have I understood this correctly? Has `rb-inotify` now broken simple commands like `gem install compass` on Ruby 1.x?

No, it is not `rb-inotify` that has broken anything.

The `compass` gem has a dependency on `rb-inotify >= 0.9`, which means that the author of the `compass` gem claims that Compass will work with *every version ever released in the future, even 10000 years from now, no matter how many changes there are*. As you have discovered, this claim is wrong, so the problem is with Compass, not with rb-inotify.

I couldn't find a versioning policy on the rb-inotify homepage, so relying on any particular versioning policy (and in particular relying on "there will never be backwards-incompatible changes, ever") is just wrong. Even if we assume that rb-inotify follows SemVer, SemVer actually allows arbitrary changes before 1.0.

In short: the gem dependency in Compass is wrong. It should be something like `rb-inotify == 0.9.0` or *at most* `rb-inotify ~> 0.9.0`, but clearly not "any version newer than 0.9.0, no matter how many changes there are".

> What is the best way to fix this without updating Ruby?

If you install `rb-inotify` version 0.9.0 *and only that version* (or at least no newer version) *before* installing Compass, then the gem requirement will already be satisfied, and RubyGems will not try to install any newer version of `rb-inotify` (unless and until you install another gem that requires a higher version).

---

Now, a question you didn't ask:

> What is the best way to fix this?

You should really consider updating your Ruby installation. I am assuming by "Ruby 1.9.3", you actually mean "YARV 1.9.3", which has not been maintained, updated, received bugfixes, and most importantly, received security fixes, since February 23rd, 2015.